# How to remove scrollbar from Mat-tab or Mat-card

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material, angular5, angular-material2

I currently have a card `(mat-card)` that inside has 2 tabs (Now you only see one tab, but the idea is to fix this problem to add the other one; which will have the same content but will serve as an example since it is only Lorem Ipsum text for the moment), what I do not find how to do is **remove the scrollbar** and that **the content just keeps stretching down the card**.

[image: Scrollbar issue]
I'm using Angular 5 and of course Angular Material 5.

I have tried several things that I found through Google and StackOverflow, none of them worked for me. I'm using Flexbox for the grid system.

My lorem.component.html code:

```html
<div class="content-padder content-background">
  <div class="uk-section-small uk-section-default header">
    <div class="uk-container uk-container-large uk-animation-slide-top-medium">
      <h1><span uk-icon="credit-card"></span> Lorem</h1>

      <p>Lorem</p>
      <ul class="uk-breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><span href="">Lorem</span></li>
        <li><span href="">Lorem</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-section-small content-padder content-background">
    <div class="container">
      <mat-card>
          <div class="mat-tab-fix">
            <mat-tab-group>
                <mat-tab class="tabs" label="Tab 1">

                        <h2 style="padding-top: 30px;">
                            <span>Lorem</span>
                          </h2>

          <div class="card-layout">
            <div class="card-column-1">

              <mat-form-field hideRequiredMarker>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Importe Recarga" required/>
                  <mat-hint align="start" matTooltip="Ingresa el importe a recargar"><p>+ Info</p></mat-hint>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-select placeholder="Lorem">
                    <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                  <mat-hint align="start" matTooltip="Lorem"><p>+ Info</p></mat-hint>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field hideRequiredMarker>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Lorem" required/>
                  <mat-hint align="start" matTooltip="Lorem"><p>+ Info</p></mat-hint>
                </mat-form-field>

            </div>

            <div class="card-column-2">
                  <mat-form-field>
                      <mat-select placeholder="Lorem Canal">
                        <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                      </mat-select>
                      <mat-hint align="start" matTooltip="Selecciona el Lorem"><p>+ Info</p></mat-hint>
                    </mat-form-field>

                    <mat-form-field>
                      <mat-select placeholder="Lorem">
                        <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                      </mat-select>
                      <mat-hint align="start" matTooltip="Lorem">+<p>+ Info</p></mat-hint>
                    </mat-form-field>

                    <mat-form-field>
                      <mat-select placeholder="Lorem">
                        <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="option">Lorem</mat-option>
                      </mat-select>
                      <mat-hint align="start" matTooltip="Selecciona el tipo de operativa"><p>+ Info</p></mat-hint>
                    </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <div class="card-column-3">
                <mat-form-field hideRequiredMarker>
                    <input matInput placeholder="Lorem" required/>
                    <mat-hint align="start" matTooltip="Lorem"><p>+ Info</p></mat-hint>
                  </mat-form-field>

                  <mat-form-field hideRequiredMarker>
                    <input matInput placeholder="Lorem" required/>
                    <mat-hint align="start" matTooltip="Lorem"><p>+ Info</p></mat-hint>
                  </mat-form-field>

                  <mat-form-field hideRequiredMarker>
                    <input matInput placeholder="Lorem" required/>
                    <mat-hint align="start" matTooltip="Lorem"><p>+ Info</p></mat-hint>
                  </mat-form-field>
                  <div class="button-row"></div>

                  <button mat-raised-button end color="primary" matTooltip="Lorem">
                      Lorem
                  </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <mat-list>
              <mat-list-item> <h2>Lorem</h2></mat-list-item>
              <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            </mat-list>

          </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
        </div>

          </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

My lorem.component.css code:

```css
.header {
  padding-top: 3.34vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
}
.content-padder {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.content-background {
  min-height: calc(100% - 80px);
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

/* Sizes and distances of Inputs */
.mat-form-field {
  padding-top: 2vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.button-row {
  padding-top: 3.34vh;
}

.mat-tab-fix {  /* Fix to the tab problem (El scroll subía al clickar en alguna de las tabs) */
  min-height:800px;
}

/* Flexbox styles for Cards and Columns */

.card-layout {
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin:  auto;
  /* line-height: 1.65; */
  padding: 20px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card-column-1 {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;

  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.card-column-2 {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;

  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.card-column-3 {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;

  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

/* .box {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width:640px;
    text-align:center;
} */

/deep/ .mat-tab-body {  /* Removing the scrollbar from the Tabs card */
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}

.mat-tab-body-content {
  height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 52):

Originally from the OP's comment on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53790290/4294399):

> Just add `dynamicHeight` [attribute] to `mat-tab-group`.

```xml
<mat-tab-group dynamicHeight></mat-tab-group>
```

See [docs on this attribute](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#dynamic-height).

Comment: this just removed the scrollbar and cut off the bottom for me

Comment: @rtaft For better visibility, you may want to just ask a new question. I don't have the familiarity with Angular or enough details to answer here. I only wrote this answer because it wis hidden in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

I Tried and it worked for me.

```
.mat-tab-body-content { overflow: hidden!important}
```

Comment: Using `!important` is a bad practise and should not be considered, unless there are no alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The h2 element inside the mat-list-item has some margin on it by default which is extending outside the mat-list element and causing the extra scrollbar. Removing the h2 or overriding the margin-bottom style will fix the problem:

```
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item>Lorem</mat-list-item>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</mat-list>
```

or

```
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item><h2 style="margin-bottom: 0;">Lorem</h2></mat-list-item>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</mat-list>
```

Comment: I eliminated the H2 and the scrollbar is still coming out. Which may be?
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Are you referring to the scrollbar inside the tab component or the scrollbar on the entire page? If the latter, remove the min-height you have set on the .mat-tab-fix class.

Comment: The mat-tab-fix is ​​because when you clicked on one of the two tabs that are, automatically scroll up. That class solves that problem, anyway I remove it and nothing happened. I mean it's the scrollbars inside the tab component.

Comment: Can you post a StackBlitz or something similar? I can't replicate the issue so it's a little difficult to solve. Or you could try removing elements from the DOM until you narrow it down to the one that's causing the problem—that's how I got it to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is pretty simple and one line change only. You just need to remove margin and/or padding for y-axis in your container tag. Your container is having default margin/padding.

Try like this:

```
<div class="container pt-0 pb-0 mt-0 mb-0">
```

Comment: It is very simple. not much code needed. give a class name to your div which is holding entire content of your card or pop up. Then got to css file and give style to that class for padding zero and margin zero to Y-axis. This can be applied anywhere. Let me know if you still need code.