# Angular how to eliminate scrollbar for mat-list

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a mat-list inside a mat-dialog. I'm trying to eliminate the scrollbar generate by the mat list but I couldn't find a solution.
selection-list.component.html:

```
<mat-list role="list">
    <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let d of data"> {{d}}</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

main-component.html:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>List</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="flex-start center">
    <selection-list></selection-list>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-list {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: Did you try CSS solutions?

Comment: I tried something like this: ```::ng-deep .mat-list {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}```

Comment: Post the demo of the code through Codesandbox or something similar so that I can debug.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778677/how-to-remove-scrollbar-from-mat-tab-or-mat-card-angular-material

Answer (score 0):

You have to override mat-dialog-content `overflow:auto` to `overflow:hidden`

```
:ng-deep .mat-dialog-content{
 overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```